# Is there something I am missing with my aggregate and find code?

Tags: java, mongodb, find, aggregate

So I have a working Python code for mongoDB, and for a class I am in right now, I am trying to put this code into Java. At the moment I have everything working correctly besides my aggregate portion, and a find command that is supposed to yield multiple results.

I have done some research which showed me it had to be in a loop for it to print out right, but I am getting same error. Also I found some stuff about maybe it being a cursor that is timing out possibly, it is a pretty big file I am working with, but some of the results for that are not working such as the .noCursorTimeout(true).

Here is my set up for the aggregate:

```
public class Aggregate {

    public static Object AggregateDocument(String input) {

        //Get mongo set up
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
        MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("market");
        MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("stocks");

        //Get the documents set up for each section of the aggregate command
        //Set up the Match
        Document match = new Document("$match", new Document("Sector", input));
        //Set up the Project
        Document project1 = new Document("_id", 1);
        Document project2 = project1.append("Shares Outstanding", 1);
        Document project3 = project2.append("Industry", 1);
        Document project4 = project3.append("Sector", 1);
        Document project = new Document("$project", project4);
        //Set up the Group
        Document group1 = new Document("_id", "$Industry");
        Document group2 = group1.append("Total Outstanding Shares", new Document("$sum", "$Shares Outstanding"));
        Document group = new Document("$group", group2);

        //Call the aggregate command
        AggregateIterable<Document> agg = collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(match, project, group));

        //Print out the result
        for (Document printAggs : agg)
        {
            System.out.println(printAggs);
        }

        return agg;
    }
}
```

Here is my code for my Find command

```
public class FindStr {

    public static Object FindString(String input) {

        //Get mongo set up
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
        MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("market");
        MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("stocks");

        //Get the documents set up 
        Document doc1 = new Document("Industry", input);
        Document doc2 = new Document("Ticker", 1);

        //Set up the find() command
        MongoCursor<Document> cursor = collection.find(doc1).projection(doc2).noCursorTimeout(true).iterator();

        //Print out the results
        while (cursor.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(cursor.next());
        }


        return cursor;
    }

}
```

For the aggregate command I am supposed to get a list of documents that fit that aggregate, and pretty much the same for the find string command. What I am getting is similar results to each other, for example here is what I am getting for the find string output:

```
Enter in a string to search for (enter it in quotes), or b to go back: 
"Medical Laboratories & Research"
Mar 30, 2019 5:52:56 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Cluster created with settings {hosts=[localhost:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
Mar 30, 2019 5:52:56 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: No server chosen by ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary} from cluster description ClusterDescription{type=UNKNOWN, connectionMode=SINGLE, all=[ServerDescription{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}]}. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out
Mar 30, 2019 5:52:56 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:3, serverValue:74}] to localhost:27017
Mar 30, 2019 5:52:56 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=localhost:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[4, 0, 6]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=7, maxDocumentSize=16777216, roundTripTimeNanos=477995}
Mar 30, 2019 5:52:56 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:4, serverValue:75}] to localhost:27017
```

Comment: In your `find()` the `"Industry"` field is matched to a **"string"**. In the `aggregate()` you are using an **integer** against that field in the `$match` here `project2.append("Industry", 1);`. That's not a "string" an if the data has a string then it will not match. Also, methods chain. i.e `new Document("key1", "value").append("key2", "value")`

Comment: I changed those to a string value but what I learned with mongoDB, the project is what you want to show, so having that ```project2.append("Industry", 1)``` 1 is true so it will show that field. This is the exact code I used for my Python run of it and it worked great, I am converting it to java. The $match is not an integer its a string, the projects have the integers but they are allowed to. Either way I converted the integers to string and its still the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I am posting my own answer because apparently the code is working fine. My inputs were wrong, with how I learned to set it up for MongoDB, I had it set up looking for an input, and usually the format for json stuff is {"key":"value"}, so when I was imputing the value part, I wanted it to be in quotes for it. But apparently if you do not put it in quotes, it works perfectly fine as intended. I have it working fine in Python so I have a working example to look at. Also, those 1's in the project portion would not work until I took them back out of string format and into integer format, those 1's really mean "true", for it to project just those keys.